# hyperv private lan with other servers

Tags: hyper-v

I have a windows server with two NICs. The first is connected to an external network and works ok. The second is connected to LAN. The second NIC is assigned 192.168.200.10.

Other servers in the LAN use are on the 192.168.200.0/24 network.

The Windows server is running Hyper-V and hosts linux guests.

I want the Hyper-V guests to also be connected to the LAN on the 192.168.200.0/24 network.

What do I need to be able to do that?

Thank you all!

Comment: It would be important to formulate more clearly. Describe your problem, use clear, round, coherent sentences. Also perfect spelling is very important. Give always more details, for others it is often not obvious what is for you. I think, your this question will be closed as unclear, but you can decrease its chance by a quick fix.

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a new Virtual Switch based on the second NIC, and add a second Network Card to your VM, pointing to the newly created Virtual Switch.

If communications will be all internal on this HYPER-V Host, you should consider using a internal Virtual Switch.

Enjoy ;)